# A way to exit the system shell (/bin/sh) from inside C

Tags: c, shell

I am doing a project which requires me to exit a Busybox shell using a C program instead of just typing "exit" when the shell is opened to exit /bin/sh.

To call /bin/sh, i just need to run

```
system("/bin/sh");
```

but when i want to exit using:

```
system("exit");
```

it doesn't work, i am quite new to C and system shell in C, and have been looking for answers for a while. Hope that someone can enlighten me on this problem. (other ways or solutions is also okay!)

Comment: The `system` function creates a *new* child process to run the command in a sub-shell. So when you use `system("exit")` you exit that sub-shell and child process. That also means running `/bin/sh` is redundant, as you'll be running a shell  from a shell.

Comment: For your problem, without knowing the *original* problem you need to solve (*why* you need to do this), means that this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). With that said, there are a few possible solutions. For example you could use a pipe connected to the child process `stdin` to send `"exit\n"`, which will not work if the shell is running a command. Or you could simply `kill` the child process. Both these solutions require you to handle the process creation and command execution yourself, rather than call `system`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you for the explanation! i am still learning about this, but unfortunately, would you help me by giving a link of an article or give an example on how to use a pipe connected to send ```"exit\n"``` ? thank you so much!

Comment: When you call /bin/sh via system(), that process lives until it decides to terminate, or it is terminated (killed). Meanwhile, your C program pauses. To forcibly terminate the child process, you should use kill()... but you can't because you are sleeping. So, first you must fork()... that's all (and is not very simple).

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica thank you so much! i will learn about fork(). But if possible, if you have any links to videos or articles that you can recommend to me for fork(), please do share it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just google for the words "fork exec". BTW, `exit` terminates the current process. If you want to malevolently a different process, you need to find its process ID and then send it a suitable signal using `kill`. I don't see why you want to do this though. From your question, I don't understand what you want to achieve in the end. Since you create an **interactive** shell with `system("/bin/sh")`, there is someone interacting with it, and this person will enter a Control-D or `exit`, if he is finished with his work.

Comment: @user1934428 thank you so much for your answer, i can tell you that there is a system that needs a user to login with their id and password. And we have a logout timer if the system is idle, the problem is that when system("/bin/sh") is opened and the logout timer is out, people could still access system shell. So i want to prevent that. It seems using fork and piping is the solution. Thank you!